# php how to get image from url without knowing extension

Tags: php, file-exists

I would like to retrieve an image from a given url, i have the filename but the issue i have is that the extension is unknown. It could be either, jpg, gif or png.

This is how i have approached it but doesnt seem to be working:

```
$extensions = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif');
    foreach ($extensions as $ext) {
        if (file_exists('https://mytestimage.com/products/3c763dce-666b-4ba9-a05a-cca846391aea/thumb.' . $ext)) {
            echo 'Found filename.' . $ext;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get any reaction?

Comment: @JakobLeifhelm nothing strangely?

Comment: lol the question has been closed but you can find what you want here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122218/get-all-the-images-from-a-folder-in-php

Comment: So what is exactly happening? It doesn't echo FoundFilename etc.. ?

Comment: This was incorrectly marked as duplicate. The question is about off-site images, *not* on-site ones. The "duplicate" in question will not work for this.

Comment: Is it possible to check if an file exists on an external website? If not your code can't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the file is off-site, check if the URL exists instead.

```
$file = 'http://example.com/image.jpg';
$fileHeaders = @get_headers($file);
if( $fileHeaders[0]=='HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')
{
    // File doesn't exist
}
else
{
    // File exists
}
```

You can apply this logic to your loop for the different extensions.

References: [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) & [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php)

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction!