# Automatically load images into WordPress slideshow from external folder

Tags: wordpress

We are looking for a solution to load images directly into a slideshow inside of a WordPress website from a folder outside of the WordPress installation. The client would upload the image files to an external folder on the server. The image files would then automatically load for each slideshow inside the WordPress website based upon folder and file name.

The client is already able to do this with their existing website, but it is not a WordPress website.

Is this possible with WordPress?

Comment: In principle, yes. But this question is pretty broad. You haven't given any details about your set up, and haven't given any indication of what you've already tried. If you do that, you're more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: You could see how to do that in php first and then use that function/s to do the rest on wp side, take a look to this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122218/get-all-the-images-from-a-folder-in-php